# How to parse slow query log from cloudwatch insights

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

How to parse mysql slow query logs from cloudwatch insights.

message looks like below

```
# User@Host: abc_ro[abc_ro] @ [x.x.x.xxx]
# Thread_id: 4935648 Schema: mytable QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 1.282014 Lock_time: 0.000154 Rows_sent: 6 Rows_examined: 964382
# Rows_affected: 0
use mydummydb;
SET timestamp=1662984070;
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

Below will parse the query time and query

```
parse @message /Query_time:\s*(?<Query_time>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*Lock_time:\s*(?<Lock_time>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)[\s\S]*?;/
| parse @message /SET timestamp=\d+;\n(?<Query>[^;]*)/
```

Comment: Could you post your results?

Answer (score 0):

This helped:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log 
| parse @message /Query_time:\s*(?<Query_time>[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?)\sLock_time:\s(?<Lock_time>[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?)[\s\S]?;/ 
| parse @message /SET timestamp=\d+;\n/*\sframework/usersessions/userinfodb.cpp:\d+\s**/\s*(?[^;]*)/ 
| sort @timestamp desc 
| limit 20
```